# Replace values in R column without impacting words with the same characters

Tags: r, string, dataframe, replace, stringr

I am trying to replace the characters ST with Street, without impacting other values within the column, such as the word Stretch. I have found that the methods attempted so far do not change to ST when it is at the end of the string, such as: 100 60TH AVE & 96TH ST    or I get something like "203 StreetREET"
where Street has replaced ST on words that are currently STREET.
I have tried to use

```
str_replace(oil_one$Facility, c("ST"), "Street")

&

oil_one$Facility[oil_one$Facility== "ST"] <- "Street"
```

Could somebody please demonstrate how to correctly do this on the column of a data frame?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. To get a solution that will work for your data can only be done if you either set out all the cases in your data or even better include a sample of `oil_one$Facility` use `dput(oil_one$Facility)` to paste this information in the questions. Guidance have a look at [MRE]. Try searching for `dplyr::mulate()` as a possible solution.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome Peter - I tried Gregor's method and it worked.

Comment: Will check out the mre now!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `\b` for word boundaries to only replace `ST` when it stands alone.

```
str_replace(oil_one$Facility, "\\bST\\b", "Street")
```

You might also want to make it ignore case:

```
str_replace(oil_one$Facility, regex("\\bST\\b", ignore_case = TRUE), "Street")
```

Comment: Worked perfectly, thank you for your help :)